# How to collect two string streams into a Map in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Arrays as below:

```
k[] = {"K1","K2","K3"}
v[] = {"V1","V2","V3"}
```

I want to iterate these two arrays using Stream API in such a way so that I collect them as a Map as

```
[K1=V1,K2=V2,K3=V3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming both arrays have the same length, you could create a stream with the indexes. This can be done with `IntStream.range(start,end)` where the start is 0 and the end the size of your array. Because we use range, the end will not be included.

In this stream, you need to collect the result to a map, the key will be the value in first array with the given index, the value will be the value in the second array with the given index.

Do note that an `IntStream` is not the same as a `Stream<Integer>`. In this case, we will need a stream of Integers so that we can collect them in the Collector (Collector does not work with primitive types). To do this, call the method `.boxed()` to convert it to a `Stream<Integer>`

```
String k[] = {"K1", "K2", "K3"};
String v[] = {"V1", "V2", "V3"};

Map<String, String> result = IntStream.range(0, k.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> k[i], i -> v[i]));
```

This gives the following result

```
{K1=V1, K2=V2, K3=V3}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
IntStream.range(0, k.length).collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> k[i], i -> v[i]));
```

Comment: Clearly you didn't test this.  It doesn't work.

Comment: nope I don't...but you should explain why it doesn't work

Comment: See @Yoni's answer.

Comment: I see...maybe it's worth to mention that Stream<Integer> is different from IntStream (for people like me)

Comment: You're not Streaming an Integer,  You're Streaming an `int` via `IntStream`.   The issue lies in the Collector.  It's not an Integer object until it is processed by `boxed()`.